# Firebase Database Read childByAutoId

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently learning ropes in Firebase for iOS, so bare with my novice skills.

Below is a screenshot of my database:

`gZ7dn2LMkiah` is the autoId for a user 
`LDBTRFVS8dtz` and `LDBTe4oXs` are autoIds for childId for this user

[image]

How can I read the two child nodes inside the node `gZ7dn2LMkiah`? 
Cause from my code below, it can only be possible if I have only one child underneath this node, not two

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userId: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("childId").child(userId).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

I tried adding `childByAutoId` after `child(userId)` but it didn't return any results.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your db seems incorrect. In first node nick and relation inside the auto key and in second node nick and relation outside the key as both are visible while the node is collapse. Although I just comment don't down vote.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. But its weird, my database doesn't show it like the image! I'll try re-uploading the image to see if it displays correctly.

Comment: Is `gZ7dn2LMkiah`  your `userId` ? I mean `userId == gZ7dn2LMkiah` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: 
 "childId").child(userId).observe(.childAdded)
   { (snapshot:DataSnapshot) in    
       // This will print all sub node  
      print(snapshot)
   }
```

Comment: Let me know this is helpful or not

Comment: Nopes :( I replaced my code with yours, and yet still it fetches no results. Again, If i remove the node and make it single node, it fetches the results. But my solution requires a key for every child, hence the second layer.

Comment: Thanks @Jignesh. It works, the correct data is fetched into the console. Now, now i need to translate this data into my tableView. Do you have any tutorials on how to? Thanks again.

Comment: Its very easy add this data on Array and reload your table

Answer (score 0):

First of all your db seems incorrect. In first node `nick and relation` are inside the `autoGeneratedKey` and in second node `nick and relation` are outside the key as both are visible while the node is collapse. So these values should be inside `autoGeneratedKey`. Please change your db structure in correct way. See below screenshot:

[image]

This will be your `childs` table containing all childs for all parents and you can query for a particular parent to get his childs. See below code snippet:

```
 ref.child("childs").queryOrdered(byChild: "parentId").queryEqual(toValue: "123").observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
     if snapshot.exists() {
         print("exists")
         for child in snapshot.children {
             let data = child as! DataSnapshot
             print(data.key)
             print(data.value)
         }
     }
     else {
         print("doesn't exist")
     }
 }
```

> **Output:**

```
-LDBus9Xas3oTccwPN4r
Optional({
    nick = Dave;
    parentId = 123;
    relation = Son;
})
-LDBus9_Uz_qe69e9CXK
Optional({
    nick = Susan;
    parentId = 123;
    relation = Daughter;
})
```

Where `parentId` is `let userId: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!`.

**Note 1: *I tried adding `childByAutoId` after `child(userId)` but it didn't return any results.***

Yes it will not work because `childByAutoId` generate a new key which will never match with existing db keys so you will get nothing.

**Note 2: *When to use `.childAdded`***

`.childAdded` event is to listen new entry for the node reference not to fetch the data. To fetch the data for once we should use `.observeSingleEvent` event.

**Note 3:*Cause from my code below, it can only be possible if I have only one child underneath this node, not two***

No its not possible. This is just because of second node's `nick` and `relation` are outside of the key.

Comment: Thanks. Im not sure how the image turned out how it is. My database displays the node correctly. I'll reupload the image. Secondly, "child as! DataSnapshot", where did you resolve "child" identifier as im getting an "unresolved" error. Thanks again for the input

Comment: let userId: String = (Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!

Comment: And this is exact equal to `gZ7dn2LMkiah` or this is just a autogenerated key?

Comment: To resolve that error you will need to `import FirebaseDatabase`.

Comment: its an autogenerated key. And yes, i have already imported firebasedatabase as well as it's reference

Comment: Then you will not get the result as `userId` will not match with your node. Try adding this in values with nick and relation and perform `equalTo` query.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts. But i really need userId as, Susan and Dave are childId to userId. Hence, userId is current user fetching results for childIds

Comment: @Roger Is it possible to modify the db structure? So I would suggest you the better way.

Comment: @Roger Updated the answer for you please check this is the right way to achieve what are you looking for.